# Firebase Login Activity Error

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have made a custom login activity that sends OTP to user's Mobile Number. As soon as User Enters Mobile Number and taps "Sends Verification Code", a white screen appears with a rotator and app crashes.

If needed, I can provide more details of its modules used by me. There is another activity in which I have Initiated mName and mPhone.

```
package com.bogdankolomiets.skydreload.data;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.Single;

public class VerifyCodeManager {
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private String mVerificationId = null;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendingToken;
private PhoneAuthCredential mPhoneAuthCredential;

@Inject
public VerifyCodeManager(FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
    mFirebaseAuth = firebaseAuth;
    mFirebaseAuth.useAppLanguage();
}

public Single<Boolean> verifyPhone(Activity activity, String phoneNumber) {
    if (mResendingToken == null) {
        return sentSms(activity, phoneNumber);
    } else {
        return resendSms(activity, phoneNumber);
    }
}

private Single<Boolean> resendSms(Activity activity, String phoneNumber) {
    return Single.create(emitter -> {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance()
                .verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneNumber,
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        activity,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                mPhoneAuthCredential = phoneAuthCredential;
                                emitter.onSuccess(true);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                                mVerificationId = s;
                                mResendingToken = forceResendingToken;
                                emitter.onSuccess(false);
                            }
                        },
                        mResendingToken

                );
    });
}

private Single<Boolean> sentSms(Activity activity, String phoneNumber) {
    return Single.create(emitter -> {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance()
                .verifyPhoneNumber(
                        phoneNumber,
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        activity,
                        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                mPhoneAuthCredential = phoneAuthCredential;
                                emitter.onSuccess(true);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                                mVerificationId = s;
                                mResendingToken = forceResendingToken;
                                emitter.onSuccess(false);
                            }
                        }

                );
    });
}

public Completable checkCode(String smsCode) {
    return Completable.create(e -> {
        if (smsCode != null && mVerificationId == null) {
            e.onError(new Throwable());
        } else {
            if (mPhoneAuthCredential == null && smsCode == null) {
                e.onError(new Throwable());
            } else if (mPhoneAuthCredential == null) {
                mPhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, smsCode);
            }
            mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(mPhoneAuthCredential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mPhoneAuthCredential = null;
                            mVerificationId = null;
                            mResendingToken = null;
                            e.onComplete();
                        } else {
                            e.onError(task.getException());
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: " app crashes" ! Well then post the stack trace of crash .

Comment: Crash Log: https://drive.google.com/open?id=13RnyGhSHtHm7di4wlcrLyMhWFPsO0Ff0

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException`

Try to log the phone number you are passing to the `sentSms()` method and make sure that phone number you are passing is in the following format :

[+][country code][user phone number]

example: +919123456780